# Having multiple loops without changing x value after first loop?

Tags: c, loops, integer, scanf

I dont know if this actually makes sense but im trying to reuse x's original value from the scanf() on the second loop so it can print what it needs to print but im having a hard time figuring it out. Is there a way in C (I'm still a beginner) to do this without using functions?

```
int main(){
    int x;
    int res1 = 0, res2 = 0;
    scanf("%u", &x);

    //reverse the digits of a number
    if (x == 0) {
        res2 = 1;
    }

    while (x != 0) {
        if (x % 10 == 0) {
            res2++;
            x /= 10;
        }
        else {
            x /= 10;
        }
    }
    
    //count number of zeroes in a number using the same value from the scanf()
    do {
        res1 = res1 * 10 + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
    } while (x != 0);
    printf("%u %u\n", res1, res2);
}
```

Comment: "im trying to reuse x's original value". Define another variable and store the original `x` into that variable.

Comment: that should be `scanf("%d", &x);` or `scanf("%i", &x);` .. `"%u"` is for `unsigned int`

Comment: `scanf()` is a function, so you cannot use values from `scanf()` without functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retain the value of `x`, you must not change `x`. `/=` operator changes value of the lefthand operand (unless the righthand operand is `1`).

Try this:

```
int main(){
    int x, x_work;
    int res1 = 0, res2 = 0;
    scanf("%u", &x);

    //reverse the digits of a number
    if (x == 0) {
        res2 = 1;
    }

    x_work = x;
    while (x_work != 0) {
        if (x_work % 10 == 0) {
            res3++;
            x_work /= 10;
        }
        else {
            x_work /= 10;
        }
    }
    
    //count number of zeroes in a number using the same value from the scanf()
    do {
        res1 = res1 * 10 + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
    } while (x != 0);
    printf("%u %u\n", res1, res2);
}
```

Or you can simply remove the part that destroy the value of `x` because `res3` changed there isn't used in later process.

```
int main(){
    int x;
    int res1 = 0, res2 = 0;
    scanf("%u", &x);

    //reverse the digits of a number
    if (x == 0) {
        res2 = 1;
    }

    //count number of zeroes in a number using the same value from the scanf()
    do {
        res1 = res1 * 10 + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
    } while (x != 0);
    printf("%u %u\n", res1, res2);
}
```